# Select Count(*) Not working in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

When i tried to `select count(*) from table` in hive . the job is stuck as shown in the screenshot. Please advise. Did I miss the setting somewhere.
But I am able to select based on where conditon.

[image]

Comment: Is "select count(1) from table" working?

Comment: No its not working Can u check the last line it  after // Can you suggest where i am going wrong

Comment: Try to repair table. Use "MSCK REPAIR TABLE sample"

Comment: Also check "hive-builtins-x.x.x.jar file in hive/lib/

Comment: You can also run ```analyze table``` query (e.g. `ANALYZE TABLE Table1 COMPUTE STATISTICS;`) & then run count to get latest stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set use of stats for small queries to false.

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false
```

Then, run `select count(*) from table` code, it should work.